# How to perform standalone migration in multi-workspace (with Angular schematics)

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-schematics

In a multi-project Angular repo, I could not manage to get the `@angular/core:standalone`-schematics to work (this allows an automatic conversion of module-based components to standalone components).

```
client
  projects
    proj1
    proj2
```

When I run `ng generate @angular/core:standalone`, no matter what my working directory is, no matter what I answer to *"Which path in your project should be migrated?"*, I always end up with the error

```
Could not find any files to migrate under the path /Users/hoeni/Work/client/projects/... Cannot run the standalone migration.
```

The absolute path shown in the error message is correct and matches the chosen directory.

Any ideas why this is not working here?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older post, hoping you found an answer by now, but I believe you need to use the relative path to your project root, not the absolute.

In my case, I was converting a specific directory, and I couldn't use the ng command since my workspace was using nx... so I had to use `npx nx g @angular/core:standalone --path=<relative_path>`